# standard in must be a tty Python script removing Sudo

Tags: python, bash, amazon-web-services, scripting, sudo

I am trying to run the command

```
"sudo service awslogs start"
```

from a python script. I cannot use 'sudo' so I change the command to

```
"su -c 'service awslogs start'"
```

but that does not seem to work either. I still get the error

su: user if=/dev/null does not exist

or

standard in must be a tty

Any ideas as to how to fix this?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/397031/run-script-as-another-user-from-a-root-script-with-no-tty-stdin

Answer (score 1):

`sudo -S` reads from stdin, see `man sudo`:

```
 -S, --stdin
     Write the prompt to the standard error and read the password from the
     standard input instead of using the terminal device.  The password must be
     followed by a newline character.
```

You can also change `/etc/sudoer` to allow your user to run the specific command without sudo.