# Thread using subprocess.communicate() throws the error: b'standard in must be a tty\\n'

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-views, subprocess

I have an issue invoking a script using subprocess.Popen() in a Thread in Python. I have added as many details as I can. Kindly let me know if I need to add more details to the issue. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**TL:DR**
subprocess.Popen() is expecting stdin and throwing the error "tandard in must be a tty" even though the script invoked doesnot require any stdin. This issue started appearing since "su userName -c" has been used while invoking the script

**Details**

I am developing a web app using django that executes PERL scripts at the backend. I am deploying the app as a root user and I intend to run the script as the user who has triggered it. I will be taking the userName from the user in the we page.

*Initial command test:*  I am logged in as root and I am using the following for starting the script as a user:

```
su userName -c ' /path_to_my_script/reImage.pm --host abcdefg --version 1.2.3.5000'
```

The above works fine as expected and runs as the user specified when I invoke it in a terminal logged in as root user. So I understand that the above command has no issues.

**Work Flow:**

When a user gives the input and submits it in the webpage, I start a daemon thread that invokes the above command in the background. Once the command is invoked, the perl script completes its task and returns the result.

I am using the following code in my views.py to create a thread (NOTE: I am writing only the lines of code related to the problem not the complete content of the views.py )

```
from threading import Thread

reImageThread = Thread(name = hostName, target = reImageFunction ,args = (hostName,buildNumber,userName) )
reImageThread.daemon = True
reImageThread.start()
```

The reImageFunction is defined in another file as follows:

```
import subprocess

def reImageFunction(hostName,buildNumber,userName):
    command = " /path_to_my_script/reImage.pm  --host  "+str(hostName)+"  --version "+str(buildNumber)+"  " #Blank space at the end is added intentionally
    command = " su " + userName + " -c \' " + command + " \' " 
    print(command)  #printing for debugging
    #The final command composed would of the format shown in the begenning of this question.
    pipe = subprocess.Popen(command , stdin=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    (result,err) = pipe.communicate()
    print(err) #Printing the err for debugging
    .... #Processing the result
    .... #Processing the result
```

The error: b'standard in must be a tty\n'  is thrown at the pipe.communicate()

I have explicitly mentioned that the stdin would be None. But I dont understand why the subprocess still expects some input.

**Observations:**

1. The issue occurs at the place where I try to use **subprocess** [pipe.communicate() ]and run the above command.
2. The above command is executes through **subprocess** without any issues when I remove the "su username -c" part, Example shown below. But this is not the expected functionality so I have to run it as the user who triggered it.

   Example command without the "su userName -c" part:

   /path_to_my_script/reImage.pm --host abcdefg --version 1.2.3.5000
3. The issue started popping up since "su userName -c" has been added.
4. I have understood that the subprocess is expecting a stdin and so throwing an error even without invoking the command.
5. The script runs as specified user when I run it from the terminal without taking/prompting for input/stdin .It doesnot require any stdin once it is invoked but I donot understand why subprocess.communicate() is expecting me to give input.

**I tried the Following:**

1. I have tried the same function without input at the pipe.communicate() but it throws same error.
2. I tried having stdin=subprocess.PIPE and pipe.communicate(input=' \n'). I was trying to give new line as stdin, but it throws the same error.
3. Tried using subprocess.call() even that throws the same error.
4. Cannot use os.system(command) as I need to analyse the output. Writing the output to a file can be a workaround if the subprocess.Popen() doesnot work at all.

Thankyou for your patience and reading till the end,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37706171/standard-in-must-be-a-tty-python-script-removing-sudo

Comment: Maybe you should use pexpect  http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html

Comment: @АндрейЧереваткин: I tried using that but it didnot work in my case so had to use the subprocess.

Comment: @Ryan: Thanks a lot, that pointer helped !! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem.

Initially, when i tried using the following from the terminal,

```
sudo -u userName command
```

I was not able to execute as I was running into the "permission denied" error. So later I started using the following command from the terminal

```
su userName -c "command"
```

This su command worked fine from the terminal. Now it was time to use it in my web application to invoke this command on the system through **subprocess.invoke(command)** and that is where I was getting the "standard in must be a tty" error.

I followed the link given by @Ryan in the comments and changed the requiretty in the /etc/sudoers file for root user as following which didnot help either.

```
Defaults:root !requiretty
```

Finally when I commented the "Defaults: requiretty" (I am aware as this might raise a security concern but it would be okey for this app) and used *su -userName command* in the subprocess.invoke(), it worked as expected. Now I am able to run the scripts as a requested user.

Thanks for reading,